# Subsetting RDDs in Spark- Python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have an `RDD` of `LabledPoints`. Is it possible to select a subset of it based on a list of indeces?

For example with `idx=[0,4,5,6,8]` , I'd like to be able to get a new RDD with elements 0,4,5,6 and 8.

Note that I am not interested about random samples, which is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can either:

1. Key your RDD by your set of values, put those values in another RDD, then do a  [leftOuterJoin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) to merge them, keeping only those in the set.
2. Put all your values into a [broadcast variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) (as a simple set) so that it gets shared across executors, the run a filter operation that validates that the points exist in your set.

Choose 1 if the list of values is large, else 2.

---

Edit to show a code sample for case 1.

```
val filteringValues = //read the list of values, same as you do your points, just easier 
            .keyBy(_)

val filtered = parsedData
            .keyBy(_.something) // Get the number from your inner structure
            .rigthOuterJoin(filteringValues) // This select only from your subset
            .flatMap(x => x._2._1) // Map it back to the original type.
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with Spark, yet. It would be great if you could post an example of option 1. Thank you,

Comment: Can you paste the piece of code where you define LabeledPoint and read it into an RDD?

Comment: hi Daniel. I'm using the python example (verbatim) from the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-support-vector-machines-svms  . I need to filter out parsedData RDD in the example, before running the SVM. Thank you,

Comment: one thing I should add is that the resulting RDD should be a copy, because I will modify it but I don't want the changes to reflect into the original RDD.

Comment: i'm not sure I understood. the list of elements idx is the list of rows I'd like to extract from the RDD. I do not have keys and values

Comment: Join operations require your RDDs to be key/value pairs, such that identical keys can be shuffled to the same executors and merged. The keyBy() operation computes a key K from your value V and produces a pair (K,V). Check the API docs for those methods. In fact, a plain join will probably work too.